# Custom Django 404 page and Django debug page

Tags: django, apache, http-status-code-404, django-settings

I am deploying a Django webpage and I love the Django Debug 404 page and and the Django page when there is a python error.  However these aren't appropriate for a webpage that is going online.  So I have made a custom 404 page.  However, for me, and my IP address, I want to still have the Django Debug pages come up.  Is there anyway to do this if I set Debug to false?

Answer (score 7):

You can define your own handler-view for 404s, by setting handler404 in your urlconf. The default handler404 is `django.views.defaults.page_not_found`, which basically just renders the `404.html` template.

If you put this in your urlconf, it will show the "technical" 404 response (the nice yellow page) for a certain IP, and use Django's default 404-production view for other IPs:

```
import sys
from django.views.debug import technical_404_response
from django.views.defaults import page_not_found

def handler404(request):
    if request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'YOUR_IP_ADDRESS':
        exc_type, exc_value, tb = sys.exc_info()
        return technical_404_response(request, exc_value)
    else:
        return page_not_found(request)
```

I would advise you to set up proper logging for you 404 errors. Django can e-mail or log 404s and exceptions for you that happens in your production environment for rules that you can specify.

See the documentation on [error reporting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#errors) and [logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) (The logging framework was added in 1.3)